# Using rep Function in R Studio

Tags: r

I'm practicing R and trying to use the rep function to produce '1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 4 5 6 7,' but for some reason, can't get a counter on the first digit to repeat through the output.

Comment: Hi Lamar, is the logic here `1:4`, then `(1:4) + 1`, `(1:4) + 2`, etc?

Comment: Why do not you want to use for loop?)

Comment: so, the solution was in creating an equation:

Comment: x = rep(0:3, each = 4) + rep (1:4, 4)